# Python Multiprocessing - freeze_support() error

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

Hi I'm trying to run multiple google chrome windows with Selenium and I need to be able to start the child processes using a function.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expect
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

PATH = "C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"

def session(state):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    driver.get(url)

    while True:
        pass


sessions = []
def runSessions():
    state = Value('i', 1)

    for i in range(2):
        p = Process(target=session, args=(state,))
        sessions.append(p)

    for p in sessions:
        p.start()

runSessions()
```

But i'm unable to even run this as whenever I call the function `runSessions()`, it throws me this error:

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Comment: You won't get any real concurrency this way. Switch to Pyppeteer for that.

Answer (score 2):

Two changes:

- When using the **multiprocessing** module in **Windows**, you need to check for main and call **freeze_support()**
- Only use a single web driver instance

Try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expect
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

PATH = "C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)

qlst = ['python','java']  # query for each instance

def session(state, idx):
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + qlst[idx]
    driver.get(url)

    while True:
        pass

sessions = []
def runSessions():
    state = Value('i', 1)

    for i in range(2):
        p = Process(target=session, args=(state,i))
        sessions.append(p)

    for p in sessions:
        p.start()

from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()  # needed for Windows
    runSessions()
```

Comment: As stated in my question, `I need to be able to start the child processes using a function.`